# Shell command to test if an app is in Rosetta 2 mode ? (check box "open with rosetta" enabled)

Tags: shell, applescript, apple-m1, rosetta

is there a shell or applescript command to find out if an universal app is forced to run in rosetta 2 mode on an M1 mac ?

If Yes, is there also a shell or applescript command to enable the check box "open with rosetta" for an app ?

I need this to test if MS Outlook runs in emulation mode or not, cause some applescripts does not work properly with Outlook in native ARM64 mode.

Thanks Armin

Answer (score 0):

You can use Activity Monitor, it shows architecture
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the hint: Do you know a terminal command to list the process name and architecture ? I've tried "top" and "ps aux" but there is no architecture visible